Sampling a mortality table
I have some mortality table:
age_range_0 yearly_probability_0
age_range_1 yearly_probability_1
...
age_range_k yearly_probability_k
over_range_k yearly_probability_over
For example:
[35,45) 0.001
[45-55) 0.003
[55-65) 0.01
[65-75) 0.03
[75-85) 0.08
[85,inf) 0.18
For discrete event simulation, how do I sample this table to obtain time-to-event (time to death) for a person given their current age?
Thanks.

One approach is construct the following table, with an example for somebody who has reached their 47th birthday:

the first column is age;
the second, the mortality rates from your table;
the third, the probability of being alive at a given birthday given they were alive age 35 (calculated as the number above multiplied by (1 - the mortality rate for the previous year);
the fourth, the probability of being alive at a given birthday given they were alive age 47 (calculated from the previous column by diving by the corresponding number for 47);
the fifth, counting years from the 47th birthday (calculated as age minus 47).

To sample from this, generate a random number uniformly from $[0, 1]$, such as say 0.56789, and find the smallest value in the fourth column greater than or equal to this, so with this example the 0.59899 corresponding to age 76, so this particular case would suggest dying 29 years later or more precisely $[29,30)$ years after their 47th birthday.
35  0.001   1       
36  0.001   0.999       
37  0.001   0.99800     
38  0.001   0.99700     
39  0.001   0.99601     
40  0.001   0.99501     
41  0.001   0.99401     
42  0.001   0.99302     
43  0.001   0.99203     
44  0.001   0.99104     
45  0.003   0.99004     
46  0.003   0.98707     
47  0.003   0.98411 1.00000  0
48  0.003   0.98116 0.99700  1
49  0.003   0.97822 0.99401  2
50  0.003   0.97528 0.99103  3
51  0.003   0.97236 0.98805  4
52  0.003   0.96944 0.98509  5
53  0.003   0.96653 0.98213  6
54  0.003   0.96363 0.97919  7
55  0.01    0.96074 0.97625  8
56  0.01    0.95113 0.96649  9
57  0.01    0.94162 0.95682 10
58  0.01    0.93221 0.94725 11
59  0.01    0.92288 0.93778 12
60  0.01    0.91366 0.92840 13
61  0.01    0.90452 0.91912 14
62  0.01    0.89547 0.90993 15
63  0.01    0.88652 0.90083 16
64  0.01    0.87765 0.89182 17
65  0.03    0.86888 0.88290 18
66  0.03    0.84281 0.85642 19
67  0.03    0.81753 0.83072 20
68  0.03    0.79300 0.80580 21
69  0.03    0.76921 0.78163 22
70  0.03    0.74613 0.75818 23
71  0.03    0.72375 0.73543 24
72  0.03    0.70204 0.71337 25
73  0.03    0.68098 0.69197 26
74  0.03    0.66055 0.67121 27
75  0.08    0.64073 0.65107 28
76  0.08    0.58947 0.59899 29
77  0.08    0.54231 0.55107 30
78  0.08    0.49893 0.50698 31
79  0.08    0.45902 0.46643 32
80  0.08    0.42229 0.42911 33
81  0.08    0.38851 0.39478 34
82  0.08    0.35743 0.36320 35
83  0.08    0.32884 0.33414 36
84  0.08    0.30253 0.30741 37
85  0.18    0.27833 0.28282 38
86  0.18    0.22823 0.23191 39
87  0.18    0.18715 0.19017 40
88  0.18    0.15346 0.15594 41
89  0.18    0.12584 0.12787 42
90  0.18    0.10319 0.10485 43
91  0.18    0.08461 0.08598 44
92  0.18    0.06938 0.07050 45
93  0.18    0.05689 0.05781 46
94  0.18    0.04665 0.04741 47
95  0.18    0.03826 0.03887 48
96  0.18    0.03137 0.03188 49
97  0.18    0.02572 0.02614 50
98  0.18    0.02109 0.02143 51
99  0.18    0.01730 0.01758 52
100 0.18    0.01418 0.01441 53
101 0.18    0.01163 0.01182 54
102 0.18    0.00954 0.00969 55
103 0.18    0.00782 0.00795 56
104 0.18    0.00641 0.00652 57
105 0.18    0.00526 0.00534 58
106 0.18    0.00431 0.00438 59
107 0.18    0.00354 0.00359 60
108 0.18    0.00290 0.00295 61
109 0.18    0.00238 0.00242 62
110 0.18    0.00195 0.00198 63
111 0.18    0.00160 0.00162 64
112 0.18    0.00131 0.00133 65
113 0.18    0.00107 0.00109 66
114 0.18    0.00088 0.00090 67
115 0.18    0.00072 0.00073 68
116 0.18    0.00059 0.00060 69
117 0.18    0.00049 0.00049 70
118 0.18    0.00040 0.00040 71
119 0.18    0.00033 0.00033 72
120 0.18    0.00027 0.00027 73
121 0.18    0.00022 0.00022 74
122 0.18    0.00018 0.00018 75
123 0.18    0.00015 0.00015 76
124 0.18    0.00012 0.00012 77
125 0.18    0.00010 0.00010 78
126 0.18    0.00008 0.00008 79
127 0.18    0.00007 0.00007 80
128 0.18    0.00005 0.00006 81
129 0.18    0.00004 0.00005 82


If you wanted precise dates from a continuous distribution for your simulation rather than years, you could assume piecewise exponential distributions, with a piecewise CDF or survival function which you can invert for a quantile function.
For example, here the survival function
$$P(X > x) = \left\{\begin{array}{rclcl}
  1 &\times &(1-0.001)^{x-35} & \text{ when } & 35 \le x \lt 45\\      
0.99004 &\times &(1-0.001)^{x-45} & \text{ when } & 45 \le x \lt 55\\      
0.96074 &\times &(1-0.003)^{x-55} & \text{ when } & 55 \le x \lt 65\\      
0.86888 &\times &(1-0.01)^{x-65} & \text{ when } & 65 \le x \lt 75\\      
0.64073 &\times &(1-0.03)^{x-75} & \text{ when } & 75 \le x \lt 85\\      
0.27833 &\times &(1-0.18)^{x-85} & \text{ when } & 85 \le x \\      
\end{array}\right.$$
(essentially the second column above, but continuous)  with inverse
$$Q(p) = \left\{\begin{array}{rclcl}
35 & + & \frac{\log(p) -\log(1 )}{\log(1-0.01)} & \text{ when } & 0.99004 \lt p \le 1\\      
45 & + & \frac{\log(p) -\log(0.99004 )}{\log(1-0.001)} & \text{ when } & 0.96074 \lt p \lt 0.99004 \\      
55 & + & \frac{\log(p) -\log(0.96074 )}{\log(1-0.003)} & \text{ when } & 0.86888 \lt p \lt 0.96074 \\      
65 & + & \frac{\log(p) -\log(0.86888)}{\log(1-0.03)} & \text{ when } & 0.64073 \lt p \le 0.86888 \\      
75 & + & \frac{\log(p) -\log(0.64073)}{\log(1-0.08)} & \text{ when } & 0.27833 \lt p \le 0.64073 \\      
85 & + & \frac{\log(p) -\log(0.27833)}{\log(1-0.18)} & \text{ when } &  0 \lt p \le 0.27833\\      
\end{array}\right.$$
To sample from this for somebody who has reached their 47th birthday (similar to my previous example), generate a random number uniformly from $(0, 1]$, such as say $0.56789$, multiply it by $P(X > 47) = 0.98411$ to give $0.55887$, then take $Q(0.55887)=76.64$ from the expression as the simulated age at death, or $29.64$ years after their 47th birthday.

Thanks Henry. I would like to have not only the interval, but a single real-number sample such as 27.8. I may suppose a constant rate in the yearly interval. After getting it, which would be the best way to extract the value?

@Carmen - I have added a continuous approach

Thanks again @Henry. You've been very helpful.
